# Objective C : How can we retrieve information stored in Local Items in key chain?

Tags: objective-c, security, keychain

I have saved the username and password for a website in safari, Safari saved this information in Local Items keychain, how can I retrieve stored information using objective C ?

I am trying to retrieve website password stored in Local Items Keychain in OS X version 10.11.4 by safari.

if I access username and password stored in login keychain. then username and password can be retrieved by below code.

```
OSStatus status;
NSString *account = @"Safari";

const char *cService_name = "PersonalFormsAutoFillDatabase";
UInt32 service_length = strlen(cService_name);

const char *cAccount_name = [account    cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
UInt32 account_length = strlen(cAccount_name);

void *passwordData = nil;
SecKeychainItemRef itemRef = nil;
UInt32 passwordLength = 0;
 status = SecKeychainFindGenericPassword(NULL, service_length, cService_name, account_length, cAccount_name, &passwordLength, &passwordData, NULL);



NSString *pw = [[NSString alloc]initWithBytes:passwordData length:passwordLength encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

When i run above code system prompt a popup and ask for permission to allow retrieve the password . if I want to change the default Login Keychain to another keychain then user need to create the reference for new keychain like below code and need to pass reference of new keychain in  SecKeychainFindGenericPassword method.

```
SecKeychainRef keychain ;
OSStatus status1 =  SecKeychainOpen("/Users/xxxx/Library/Keychains/mykeychain.keychain", &keychain);
if(status1 != errSecSuccess) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to open System keychain %@", SecCopyErrorMessageString(status1, NULL));

}
status1 = SecKeychainUnlock(keychain, 0, NULL, FALSE);
```

My First question is what will be path for Local Items keychain like “/Users/xxxx/Library/Keychains/mykeychain.keychain” ?

As I don’t have the path then i created a new keychain From File->Add KeyChain and give the name testing.keychain. After that I copied one keychain item form  Local Items keychain and Pasted into testing.keychain. and used the above code and changed the path as below.

```
SecKeychainRef keychain ;
OSStatus status1 =  SecKeychainOpen("/Users/xxxx/Library/Keychains/testing.keychain", &keychain);
if(status1 != errSecSuccess) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to open System keychain %@", SecCopyErrorMessageString(status1, NULL));

}
status1 = SecKeychainUnlock(keychain, 0, NULL, FALSE);
```

and passed the reference in find generic password method and also change the service name and account name to "a@gmail.com" and service name "https://accounts.google.com"

```
status = SecKeychainFindGenericPassword(keychain, service_length, cService_name, account_length, cAccount_name, &passwordLength, &passwordData, NULL);
```

this return the password data but as i think it is in encrypted mode then it return NULL. How can I decrypt this stored password.

Anyone who can help so i can retrieve the password stored in Local Items keychain.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you read the [Keychain Services Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/01introduction/introduction.html) and associated API documents?

Comment: @CRD Thanks for providing link. I have tried using keychain API. As Local Keychain Items are encrypted . used function SecKeychainFindGenericPassword(keychain, strlen(srviceName), srviceName, strlen(acct), acct, &passwordLen, &password, NULL). but it returns null because Local Items are encrypted. if use for Login keychain items then function returns the result.

Comment: Which keychain an item is in should not make any difference, your app just needs to acquire the appropriate permissions (usually dialogs come up). Check the password you are looking for in Keychain Access, is it encoded? What are the permissions on the item? Etc. If you can't figure it out edit your question and provide more details, code, etc. and someone might be able to help you.

Comment: The local Items keychain is not a regular keychain but a DB: [THE “LOCAL ITEMS” KEYCHAIN IN MAVERICKS](https://macmule.com/2014/03/30/the-local-items-keychain-in-mavericks/). It does not appear to respond to the `SecKeychainRef` methods such as `SecKeychainCopySearchList()`. I'm struggling to access the keychain items in Local Items from my macOS app. Any further help/clues would be most appreciated.